# Cropping PDF using iText (java PDF library)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to crop PDF file using this [code](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=280). `cb` will output the needed coordinates for the cropping.

How can efficiently do this for every page in a PDF file?

Did this code, but does not work for every pdf input:

```
public class CropPages {

public static final String PREFACE = "input.pdf";
public static final String RESULT = "cropped.pdf";


public void addMarginRectangle(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    TextMarginFinder finder;
    PdfDictionary pageDict;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        finder = parser.processContent(i, new TextMarginFinder());
        //PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle((finder.getLlx()-5), (finder.getLly()-5), (finder.getUrx()+5), (finder.getUry()+5));
        if (i <= 10){
                 System.out.println(rect);
                 }
        pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
        pageDict.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect);
     }
    stamper.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    new CropPages().addMarginRectangle(PREFACE, RESULT);
}
```

}

Comment: why isn't working for you? I used your code to crop 10,000 files (one pagers though) and had no problem.

Comment: *Did this code, but does not work for every pdf input* - please explain in which way it fails for some PDFs and share an example PDF to reproduce the issue with. I can think of some situations it fails for, e.g. if there is off-page text in the content stream (resulting in a too large crop box) or if the text is not regular text (resulting in a too small crop box). The code assumes PDFs to be generated in a *normal* manner.